# Creating and adding median, mean etc. in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame R_m which looks like this:

[data frame R_m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvyzQ.png)

I have used pivot_longer to modify the data for ggplot and then print it:

```
 R_m2 <- R_m %>%
     pivot_longer(names_to = "per", values_to="ind", cols=-sim, names_ptypes=list(per=integer()))

ggplot(R_m2, aes(x=per, y=ind,color=sim, group=sim))+geom_line() + 
        theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Now, I would like to add a line for mean, median and some quantiles in the graph. Before, I got this data from elsewhere and imported it as a data frame 'stat' into R. It looks like this:

[median, mean and quantile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi2P8.png)

which plotted nicely by adding

```
geom_line(data=subset(stat,sim=="Median"),colour="black", size = 1)
```

Outcome looks like this:
[image: Outcome]

Now I would like to achieve the same in R. Creating an array of medians (where median is taken across each column in R_m) was straightforward to do. But then my first stumbling block was that using rbind, cbind etc. I could not create a data frame that looks like 'stat'. I could not rename the zero column to "sim", so the geom_line command above no longer works. Anyway, this requires a lot of data manipulation. Is there a more efficient way of adding a median, mean and percentile lines to a graph?

```
structure(list(sim = c(166, 37, 163, 65, 95, 92, 98, 168, 19, 
157, 177, 200, 115, 177, 149, 130, 66, 114, 96, 12, 138, 39, 
80, 33, 157, 107, 180, 159, 166, 14, 126, 67, 190, 86, 147, 182, 
43, 5, 109, 141, 53, 186, 49, 68, 168, 107, 67, 28, 158, 178), 
    per = c(407L, 1763L, 2158L, 1608L, 836L, 1638L, 285L, 1978L, 
    45L, 1927L, 192L, 1517L, 163L, 789L, 1989L, 2478L, 2410L, 
    2445L, 1532L, 181L, 1489L, 1434L, 2515L, 676L, 1503L, 2458L, 
    732L, 1266L, 1705L, 1852L, 1543L, 1568L, 41L, 1992L, 600L, 
    1314L, 33L, 199L, 370L, 46L, 1171L, 1173L, 2048L, 994L, 836L, 
    372L, 2374L, 1414L, 1628L, 1188L), ind = c(97.7428137181456, 
    100.462039003802, 95.2793483563514, 98.3721036305918, 99.0584691732282, 
    103.301132288618, 102.428408453689, 100.387198613893, 99.7888039221544, 
    101.017059784079, 106.12288506898, 102.636429823681, 93.8144062244855, 
    104.280572544198, 97.3182467653953, 96.5603916025096, 96.3529141792467, 
    98.3149638711415, 98.3629878947972, 94.6106342501915, 99.6835722307572, 
    98.1716050345778, 103.055895201755, 100.054976695486, 96.1369802984859, 
    98.5257212288309, 98.8568719059079, 102.900859147552, 99.37215427561, 
    102.623437273663, 104.128600607447, 102.673062489082, 100.368131206055, 
    98.3487549118012, 96.4401682804699, 96.4407823981984, 97.9413312935541, 
    102.122624393907, 98.2979203190445, 101.018531709501, 100.444354410774, 
    101.118257199515, 100.867412455804, 98.9923953588876, 100.417977446024, 
    102.21423103019, 102.296794518966, 99.9367239162818, 102.314273028354, 
    100.80711113148)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, try to avoid screen capture and rather prefer to give data example using `dput` or `head` on your data, and try to give a minimal working example, see [mcve]

Comment: Hi OP, welcome to SO!  Adding to @denis, images are great for sharing plots, which would be really useful in this case to share a plot of (1) what you are getting and either through text of the question or through a picture, show what you want.  Of course, putting your data into the body of the question (formatted as code) by copying and pasting the output of `dput(your.data.frame)` is probably the most preferred way of sharing data.  If your dataset is too large, either use a built-in dataset for R (`iris`, `mtcars`...) or sample your data: `dput(your.df[sample(1:nrow(your.df), 50),])`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I added the outcome created using imported mean, median etc series.

Comment: Although you can do this by making a separate data frame, you should be able to create those lines directly using `stat_summary()` from your melted dataset (`R_m2`).  Can you provide a sample of that dataset as indicated above?  It would probably be sufficient to copy and paste the *output* of `dput(R_m2[sample(1:nrow(R_m2), 50),]` directly into your question (formatted as code).